# how to delete a file on the server and add a new file based on clients choice

Tags: php

I have roughly figured out how to upload a file the server IF the file does not exist. Now if the file exist I would like the client to be able to overwrite/delete the existing file and upload the New file. Yes, both files must have the same name.

So what I was attempting to do was when the file existed use a switch statement that calls a function that will either delete the existing file and upload the new file Or force php code to die therefore canceling the upload

```
    if (isset($_GET['run'])) $linkchoice=$_GET['run']; 
    else $linkchoice=''; 

    switch($linkchoice){ 
      case 'one' : 
          upload_file();
          break;
      case 'two' : 
          kill();
          break;
```

then us a link to execute a function

```
   <a class=button href='?run=one'>Replace Existing File</a><br/>
   <a class=button href='?run=two'>Cancel Upload</a>
```

Here is how I tried to put it all together.

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);


    $allowedExts = array("xml");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/xml")
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }

      else{
        if (file_exists("SIMxml/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){

        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " file already exists.<br/>";
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
        $size = ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024);

       /* if (isset($_GET['run'])) $linkchoice=$_GET['run']; 
          else $linkchoice=''; 

            switch($linkchoice){ 

            case 'one' : 
              upload_file($file,$type,$size,$temp); 


            case 'two' : 
              kill(); 

            }

           echo "<a class=button href='?run=one'>Replace Existing File</a><br/>";
           echo "<a class=button href='?run=two'>Cancel Upload</a>"; */

           }

         else{
           echo "File: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
           echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
           echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";

           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
           "/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
           echo "Stored in: " . "SIMxml/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
           }
        }
     }
     else{
       echo "Invalid file";
       }

   ?>

   <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);

   function delete_file($file){
     unlink("/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file);
     }
   function upload_file($file,$type,$size,$temp){
     echo $file;
     delete_file($file);

     echo "File: " . $file . "<br>";
     echo "Type: " . $type . "<br>";
     echo "Size: " . $size . " kB<br>";

     move_uploaded_file($temp,
     "/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file);
     echo "Stored in: " . "SIMxml/" . $file;
     }
   function kill(){

     }

   ?>
```

Obviously this does not work, and I am struggling with Tying or implement several concepts/ideas together.

I would appreciate some advice on figuring out how to implement this.

Thank you in advance, JD

Comment: unlink('/var/www/jd/SIMxml/'.$filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, @Jacob S got me think of how to separate my request, and instead of creating a session or implementing a "pre-upload" request I went with a different route, sort of.

In the first version of the code (the original question) I tried to embedded a switch statement into a logic operation and it appeared to fail because the parameter for the file was not being passed. So to get around this,

first: I check to see if the file exist and if it does then create a pseudo temp file from the actual temp file.

```
    if (file_exists("/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file)){
              $ftemp = "/var/www/jd/temp/" . $file;
              move_uploaded_file($tmp,
              $ftemp);
```

To get the $tmp file name from the form I used

```
    $tmp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

Second: I used a hyperlink that when selected it will call the php file delete.php, from what I understand. Embedded in the hyperlink are the parameters that are needed to rename the pseudo temp file.

```
    echo "<p><a class=button href='delete.php?run=one&file=$file&temp=$temp'>
          Replace Existing File</a></p>";
    echo "<p><a class=button href='delete.php?run=two&file=$file&temp=$ftemp'>
          Cancel Upload</a></p>";
    die();
```

Third: Set up my functions in the delete.php file

```
    <?php
    function delete_file($file){
       unlink("/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file);
       if (file_exists("/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file)){
           echo "SIMxml/" . $file. " Was not deleted";
    }
    function upload_file($file,$temp){
        rename ($temp, "/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file);

        if (file_exists("/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file)){
            echo "Stored in: " . "SIMxml/" . $file;
        }
        else{
            echo $file,"<br/>";;
            die ("File was not uploaded.");
        }
    }
    function kill($temp){
        unlink($temp);
        die('The upload was canceled');
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the php segment that calls both the delete and upload functions to complete the upload process. You could use a switch statement here but choose not too.

```
    <?php
    if($_REQUEST['run'] == 'one'){
        delete_file($_GET['file']);
        upload_file($_GET['file'],$_GET['temp']);
    }
    if($_REQUEST['run'] == 'two'){
        kill($_GET['temp']);
    }
    ?>
```

I am assuming that the hyperlink creates some type of associative array and the $_Get retrieves the parameters with in the array, not quite sure how that works yet. but I know it gets what I need

```
        upload_file($_GET['file'],$_GET['temp']);
    }
    ?>
```

Now, is the the best way to accomplish what I wanted to do? probably not, but it is working so far. I should also state, if it is not obvious, that pieced a fair amount of this together from other questions here on stackoverflow and other sites, this is not an "Original" idea and it may be the worst way to accomplish the task at hand, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer, but not suitable for a comment:

```
    if (file_exists("SIMxml/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
```

Here you use a relative path, but if your script EVER changes its current working directory, you'll end up with no end of trouble because elsewhere:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . ...
```

and

```
unlink("/var/www/jd/SIMxml/" . $file);
```

you use absolute paths. Not a good idea.

Comment: So I should stick with one or the other, right. Considering I know that the directory location will NEVER change in my foreseeable future, but I will ,more than likely, change the php file location, I should stick to using the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you have two separate requests -- the first was the uploading of a file, the second your are trying to set an option but you don't have the "file" anymore because it is a new request.

You either need to:

1. Store a reference to the file that was uploaded somewhere, such as in a session, or
2. Change your process so that the determination is made before the file is uploaded, such as using a (a)synchronous javascript request to determine whether the filename that will be uploaded already exists and use that determination to request additional input before allowing the submit/upload -- a pre-upload request of sorts.